# Expect script to power on ilo2, works fine but no exit

Tags: expect

This is my script to power on a ILO2 HP server.
Works fine(the server power on) but after the power on the ilo console remain open and I can exit from script only using ctrl+c
by hand, so the script is not full non-interactive, how to pass
a correct ^D to exit from console?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
              ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}

set timeout -1
set send_slow {1 .1}
spawn csh
match_max 100000
expect -exact "% "
sleep .1
send -s -- "ssh hpilo2\r"
expect -exact "ssh hpilo2\r\r
This is a private system. It is to be used solely by authorized users and may be monitored for all lawful purposes. By accessing this system, you are consenting to such monitoring.\r
\rmyuser@hpilo2's password: "
sleep .1
send -s -- "mypass\r"
expect -exact "\r
User:myuser logged-in to hpilo2.(******* / *********)\r
\r
iLO Advanced **** at  Feb 28 2041\r
Server Name: \r
Server Power: Off\r
\r
</>hpiLO-> "
sleep .1
send -s -- "power on\r"
expect -exact "
\r\r
status=0\r
status_tag=COMMAND COMPLETED\r
Sat Dec 6 12:38:17 2031
\r
\r
\r
Server powering on .......\r
\r
\r
\r
</>hpiLO-> "
sleep .1
send -- "^D"
expect eof
```

Comment: For Ctrl+D, use `send -- \004`

Comment: I made it and doesn't work

Comment: Run the script with `expect -d scriptname` and show the verbose debugging output

Comment: thanks, but I found another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found
CTRL+D make nothing on my hpilo shell
the command for exit the shell is.. exit.
So I modify the latest lines of script

```
Server Name: \r
Server Power: Off\r
\r
</>hpiLO-> "
sleep .1
send -s -- "power on\r"
sleep 2
send -s -- "^exit\r"
```

and now works perfectly